# How can I access currently processed Broccoli trees from an addon's index.js file?

Tags: ember-cli, broccolijs, ember-cli-addons

I am working on a new in-repo addon, and I want to copy a file from the `public` tree to my own addon's namespace.

I've specified that my addon should run after `broccoli-asset-rev`, because the file I want is the `assetMap.json` file generated by this plugin.

I've been able to use `treeForAddon` to write new files to my own addon's namespace (which I can then import in my application code), but my question is, can I read from the currently-built public tree in this hook? Ideally I'd like to do something like this:

```
module.exports = {
  name: 'my-new-addon',

  treeForAddon() {
    let publicTree = this.getTreeFor('public'); // does something like this exist?
    let newTree;

    // Read assets/assetMap.json from the public tree, and
    // write it to a file called asset-map.json in newTree

    return this._super.treeForAddon.call(this, newTree);
  }
};
```

That would allow me to do the following in my Ember app code:

```
import assetMap from 'my-new-addon/asset-map';
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `treeForPublic`?

https://ember-cli.com/api/classes/Addon.html#method_treeForPublic